# Weak and weak$^*$ topologies

Tags: functional-analysis

I have some confusion about weak and weak* topologies. What I have understood is as bellow.

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $X^*$ be its topological dual. Then the coarsest Hausedorff topology on $X$ generated by the inverse images of the open sets in $\mathbb K$ under $f\in X^*$ is called the weak topology on $X$. That means weak topology is the coarsest topology on $X$ for which each $f$ is continuous.

Please help me to understand what is weak* topology on $X^*$.

Comment: did you define it through the bidual?

Comment: I have understood something as follows: 
Every element of $X$ can be identified as a bounded linear functional on $X^*$. The topology on $X^*$ generated by the inverse images of the open sets on $\mathbb K$ under those bounded linear functional on $X^*$ (elements of $X$) is the weak* topology on $X^*$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. If $F$ is a vector space of linear forms on the vector space $E$, then one denotes the topology generated by the inverse images of open subsets of $\mathbb{K}$ under the functionals in $F$ by $\sigma(E,F)$. Thus, the weak topology on $X$ is $\sigma(X,X^\ast)$, and the weak$^\ast$ topology on $X^\ast$ is (with the canonical identification of $X$ with a subspace of $X^{\ast\ast}$) $\sigma(X^\ast, X)$ - whereas the weak topology on $X^\ast$ is $\sigma(X^\ast, X^{\ast\ast})$. The weak and weak$^\ast$ topology on $X^\ast$ coincide if $X$ is reflexive.